# Multiple many-to-many relations through the same model in Django problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have a problem i don't know how to make multiple many-to-many relations through the same model.

This is my DB relations :

[Db architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKcpD.jpg)

and this is my code, i want to know if what I did is right or not ?

```
class Projects(models.Model):

  Project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  Poject_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  CITools = models.ForeignKey(CITools,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  UsersO = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='OwnerShips') # for user Ownerships
  UserF = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='Favorites') # for user Favorites
```

This is my OwnerSHips class :

```
class OwnerShips(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And this is my Favorites Class:

```
class Favorites(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  project = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the solution, i used the attribute related_name, so Django to create this two tables automatically

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use foreign keys (ownerships and favorites) in Project before those classes are created.